# Android: Make imageView clickable on animation

Tags: java, android, imageview, translate-animation

I have an imageView that currently just moves from left to right of the screen with translateAnimation. I would like the user to click the imageView as it goes across the screen and then this would set the ImageView to INVISIBLE. My problem is because I use Translate Animation this can not be done. What is the way I should do this? and could an example be provided.

My code:

```
package com.example.mr_br.ibcc_bomber_command;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class front_gunner extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_gunner);
    //sets screen orientation on created
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    //animation
    final TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(-400, 2500, 0, 0);
    moveLefttoRight.setDuration(10000);
    moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(false);



    //enemies
    final ImageView enemy1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.enemy1);

    enemy1.setAnimation(moveLefttoRight);

    enemy1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enemy1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });



}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: try to stop the animation inside the OnClickListener.

Comment: This is odd because it works for the first second of the animation and the imageview becomes INVISIBLE but after that it is unclickable...

Comment: why you need to detect click events for invisible view?

Comment: I need to click it to make it invisible, see it as a game with an enemy flying across the screen, a click destroys it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) approach is much more pleasant:

```
enemy1.animate()
    .translationX(2500.0f)
    .setDuration(10000)
    .withStartAction(() -> enemy1.setTranslationX(-400.0f));
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came to:

```
 ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(enemy1, "translationX", -400f, 2500f);
    anim.setDuration(10000);                  // Duration in milliseconds
    anim.start();
```

I used a different type of animator. This worked great. If anyone else encounters the same issue this is a decent solution.